# Is it possible to modify the source code from gdb?

Tags: gdb

I was just wondering if it is possible to modify the source code directly  from gdb (with gdb -tui for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with gdb -tui for example

No, `gdb -tui` is a read only view of source code. But you can use `edit` command to start your favorite editor and edit source code:

```
$ EDITOR=vim gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) 
...
...
...
(gdb) edit
```

See also builtin help:

```
(gdb) help edit 
Edit specified file or function.
With no argument, edits file containing most recent line listed.
Editing targets can be specified in these ways:
  FILE:LINENUM, to edit at that line in that file,
  FUNCTION, to edit at the beginning of that function,
  FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions.
  *ADDRESS, to edit at the line containing that address.
Uses EDITOR environment variable contents as editor (or ex as default).
```